# 1D Time independent Schrodinger eq. with limit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

The one dimensional Schrodinger equation for an exponential potential

$$-{\hbar^2\over 2m} \frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}+-\alpha\frac{e^{-\vert x\vert\over\epsilon}}{2\epsilon}\psi=E\psi$$

I am interested in solving this equation with the limit as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. My goal is to check the equivelance between the dirac delta function explicit bound state solution with the above representation.

is it reasonable to solve this equation and then dealing with the limit, and how?

Comment: So... what's the question here?

Comment: is it reasonable to solve this equation and then dealing with the limit, and how?

Comment: I don’t think this potential has an analytical solution...

Comment: Do we even know what the $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{\exp{-\vert x\vert\over\epsilon}}{2\epsilon}$ is?

Comment: @Gert pretty sure it's a Dirac delta.